# Issues using Spyder Python to connect to a remote machine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark, spyder

I have a Red Hat system in AWS running Spark on top of [HDFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Hadoop_distributed_file_system). Now I want to access [PySpark](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/index.htm) from my local machine, i.e., *interactive* Python.

So, I installed Spyder-Py2 to connect to the remote AWS machine, so I can access Spyder Python.

Route:

- Using [Cookbook: Connecting to a remote kernel via ssh](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh), I started the kernel on the AWS machine, i.e., the server and copied the JSON file over to the local machine.
- Changed the IP address in kernel1234.json to point to the public IP address.
- Went to Consoles in Spyder-Py2 and select "Connect to existing kernel".
- Passed the *kernel1234.json* file, added username and host in the hostname section.
- Passed my AWS [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) key in the SSH Key section and entered the password

But it fails with the below error:

> Unable to connect to IPython kernel-1234.json

What am I missing here?

Note: The server on the AWS VM is still running.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the exact same problem; Did you managed to resolve it?

Comment: Not yet! Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: yes actually I did. Make sure the .json file you save as the same name as given in the bottom part of the %connect_info values that you retrieve from Jupyter. ALso that .json as to be saved with all the other .json kernel that Jupyter creates on the fly. Not sure where that dir is located but Spyder will prompt you to select the kernel by default, so that's the way you can find that folder.

Comment: Try to ssh into your AWS machine : ssh -i /path/to/your/pem/key.pem username@your-aws-host, to narrow down the problem